# how to make a CORS ajax post request to a json server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to maka a cross domain POST request to a json server using jquery ajax in the code snippet below:

```
          var URL = $("#postUrl");
          $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: {
                "id": 8,
                "first_name": "Mark",
                "last_name": "Green",
                "phone": "409-324-1345",
                "email": "mark@nexware.com.ng",
                "prefered_exam": "NECO",
                "institution": "greenchamber"
            },
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            async:true,
            crossDomain:true,
            dataType:"json",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            accepts:{
              "*": "*/*",
              text: "text/plain",
              html: "text/html",
              xml: "application/xml, text/xml",
              json: "application/json, text/javascript"
            },
            success: function ( data ) {
                alert( data );
            }
        });
```

this doesn't even appear to do anything but refresh the page. Someone please help by pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Do you have access to server code ??

Comment: No, just the API

Comment: I believe you can't make "json"  ajax post .. i read something about "jsonp" but you need to modify the server if you find anything please share the answear

Comment: I get you but, I use curl and it works, I also use the postman tool and it works as well, but ajax isn't working

Comment: Postman can make a CORS request same for curl but javascript is restricted by the browser .. you can bybass this in google chrome development tools somehow but not suitable for production

Comment: You are not sending json...need to stringify it. Also will depend on whether api is CORS enabled or not. If page is refreshing it sounds like this is also implemented using a form and need to prevent default form submit

Comment: @charlietfi, thanks for ur answer, I used stringify and it worked very well, I can now post to the server.

Comment: Please, @charlietfi post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer and +1 it. Thanks